# Is ConnectionKit still usable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing a Cocoa app that will need access to multiple file transfer protocols, such as FTP, Amazon S3, etc, and I was planning on using the ConnectionKit framework to implement them. However, even though I managed to get it compiled (which is quite a feat itself), it seems to be missing a number of it's header files, such as the S3 protocol.

My question is this: has anyone actually managed to build a working copy of ConnectionKit recently, and if so, how did you do it?

Thanks in advance!
SphereCat1

http://opensource.utr-software.com/connection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConnectionKit is now at http://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit

Comment: Thanks for passing this along, but this branch has the exact same issues as the one on the site.